# PHP no guarda registros con Llave Primaria

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un formulario PHP sencillo que inserta datos a una tabla, pero, si mi tabla tiene un campo "ID" que es llave primaria y autoincremental, no me deja insertar, se salta al error. En cambio, si elimino mi llave primaria y dejo los puros campos que uso en el formulario si se insertan los datos sin problemas.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe esto?

Form:

```
<form action="reservar.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="txt_fecha" placeholder="Fecha de Reservación">
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="txt_hora" placeholder="Hora de Reservación">
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="txt_personas" placeholder="Cantidad de Personas">
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Reservar" class="btn btn-warning">
    </form>
```

Archivo insertar datos:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$nombre = $_POST['txt_nombre'];
$fecha = $_POST['txt_fecha'];
$hora = $_POST['txt_hora'];
$cantidad = $_POST['txt_personas'];
$orden = "12345";

$insertar = "INSERT into res values 
('$nombre', '$fecha', '$hora', '$cantidad', '$orden')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar) or die ("Error al Insertar");

include 'cerrar_conexion.php';

echo "Datos insertados correctamente";

?>
```

Tabla:

```
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `res`
--

CREATE TABLE `res` (
  `id_res` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cliente` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_res` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `hora_res` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cant_personas` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `orden` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `res`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_res`);

ALTER TABLE `res`
  MODIFY `id_res` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Mostrar el mensaje personalizado en el `die` no es muy útil, pues no muestra cuál es el error específico al intentar ejecutar la consulta. Trata de mostrar el mensaje de excepción y revisa los logs de PHP para ver cuál es la excepción (y edita tu pregunta para añadir esta información)

Comment: Lo otro: tampoco sabemos cuál es la definición de la tabla, añádela también. Así el que te intenta responder no tiene que adivinar y puede ayudarte de forma más efectiva.

Comment: @Alfabravo conviene aclarar que los errores internos sólo deberían mostrarse en fase de depuración del código, al pasar a producción hay que usar mensajes personalizados, pues los mensajes internos revelan información útil que puede ser explotada por usuarios mal intencionados.

Comment: @A.Cedano 300% cierto, válido y relevante.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por las observaciones, ya he agregado la estructura de la tabla, los errores los puse solo para observar si el proceso se realizaba correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El fallo está en el SQL:

```
$insertar = "INSERT into res values 
('$nombre', '$fecha', '$hora', '$cantidad', '$orden')";
```

Prueba así:

```
$insertar = "INSERT into res values 
(NULL,'$nombre', '$fecha', '$hora', '$cantidad', '$orden')";
```

O así:

```
$insertar = "INSERT into res 
(cliente,fecha_res,hora_res,cant_personas,orden)
values 
('$nombre', '$fecha', '$hora', '$cantidad', '$orden')";
```

Totalmente de acuerdo con los comentarios, sin el `die()` hubieras recibido un error del tipo: número de campos incorrecto y lo hubieras detectado.

Todo apuntaba a que se te habia olvidado definir ese campo `ID` como `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Probando con:

```
ALTER TABLE res MODIFY `ID` int AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Si entonces te funcionaba era porque, al no ser `AUTO_INCREMENT` y sí `PRIMARY KEY` y `NOT NULL`, insertaba por defecto un `0`. Con el primer registro no pasaba nada pero, con el resto, al ser valores duplicados, activan la restricción de duplicados y te impiden registrar el dato. Pero bueno, era aún más sencillo que eso :)

Comment: Hola @David JP, si tenía bien definido el `ID`, era `PRIMARY KEY`, `INT`, `AUTO_INCREMENT `y `NOT NULL`, no inserta ni siquiera el primer registro, simplemente me pasa directo al `DIE`

Comment: Ok, acabo de modificar la respuesta. Ya me dices si era eso...

Comment: correcto, efectivamente el error estaba en el SQL, ya adapté el código a tu ejemplo. Gracias por la ayuda.